# Algorithm to find clusters using competitive networks

Tags: python, algorithm, neural-network, cluster-analysis, array-broadcasting

below attached the algorithm which i'm implementing. (which is a well known algorithm for competitive learning)

[image: Algorithm]

this is to cluster iris data using competitive learning(neural network).
i have written the algorithm for above. but it does't cluster the data accurately. most of the times it clusters the data for the 1st cluster of the data set. i have tried with different learning rates and interactions, but cannot improve the accuracy. did i do any mistake while writing above algorithm? 
if not what should i do to improve the clustering with this algorithm?

```
#initialize wights randomly ( used 3 neurons as there are 3 clusters,4 variables )
W = np.random.rand(3,4)

#Weights normalization 
W = preprocessing.normalize(W)

#Normalize X
X = np.matrix(preprocessing.normalize(X))


t =[]
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(1,500):
        wx = np.argmax(np.dot(W,X[i].getT()))
        #update winner neuron
        W[wx:] = W[wx:]+0.3*(X[i]-W[wx:])
        W = preprocessing.normalize(W)
    t.append(wx)
    #print(wx)
print(W)
```

Comment: Are you *developing* the algorithm or *implementing* it?

Comment: implement the given algorithm. it's a well known algorithm i guess

Comment: Then you should write that. If you ask "I am developing an algorithm and it doesn't work", everyone will think it is because your algorithm is bad.

Comment: thank you. i have edited the post accordingly